# how do I apply woocommerce coupon code using my keyboard enter key?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On the backend, I add a coupon code. If I click the submit button the coupon code will apply. How do I apply my coupon code pressing the enter key in mobile and desktop? Some users will press enter instead using the mouse to click button. Default woocommerce doesn't have that feature. how do I make it work? Thanks

```
$("#inputbox").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('input[type=submit]').click();
    }
});


<form id="testt" action="<?php echo esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table' ); ?>

                <div class="coupon">

                    <?php if ( WC()->cart->coupons_enabled() ) { ?>

                    <span for="coupon_code"><?php _e( 'Coupon code:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span> 

                    <div class="input-container">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <input id="inputbox" class="input" type="text" name="coupon_code" value="" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'bebrave', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" /> 
                        </div>
                        <input type="submit" class="ds btn" name="apply_coupon" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Apply Coupon', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />

                        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_coupon' ); ?>
                    </div>

                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php wc_print_notices(); ?>

                    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_actions' ); ?>

                    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-cart' ); ?>

                </div>

                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_contents' ); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_table' ); ?>

            </form>
```

Comment: All input type submit behave when enter is clicked.. it means some code already done for this button. also when u use event.preventDefault(); you disable your form action. so nothing will work at all

Comment: Ilan is correct. Pressing enter always submits a form unless something else is blocking it.